# How many frames is it when I call videoWriter.write?

Tags: opencv, python

```
videoWriter = cv2.VideoWriter('video_demo.avi', cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), 10, size)  

success, frame = videoCapture.read()  

while success :  
    cv2.imshow("Video demo", frame) 
    videoWriter.write(frame) 
    success, frame = videoCapture.read()  
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27: 
        break  # esc to quit
```

In constructor function of VideoWriter, I set the fps is 10.
But I call videoWriter.write(frame) function more than 10 times per second.
So my question is what is the real fps in my saved video and which frames are saved?

Comment: All the input frames are obviously saved, with a constant fps of 10.

Comment: Input 100 fps when set fps as 10, what is the result?

Comment: Will it save 10 fps? which 10 fps in input 100 fps will be saved?

Comment: The fps of output video would depend on the 3th positional argument passed to `cv2.VideoWriter` which is 10 in your case, The fps of input video doesn't plays any role here, fps of output video is going to be 10 only.